# Usar uma variável criada dentro de uma requisição AJAX em outra função

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho uma lista de projetos em que, quando o thumb de um projeto é clicado, o script carrega as imagens relacionadas ao projeto.

```
$('.project-grid').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var id_projeto = $this.data('projeto');
    pega_imagens(id_projeto);
});
```

A última linha chama a seguinte função:

```
function pega_imagens(id_projeto){
    var id_projeto = id_projeto;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({ id_projeto: id_projeto }),
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'php/imagens.php',
        success: function (data) {
            var toAppend = '';
            toAppend += '<div class="gutter-sizer"></div><div class="grid-sizer"></div>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                toAppend += '<img class="item" src="img/' + data[i].imagem + '" width="' + data[i].largura + '" height="' + data[i].altura + '" />';
            }

            $('#project-expander-images-'+id_projeto).append(toAppend);
            alturaTotal = $('#project-expander-images-'+id_projeto).height();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('erro' + data);
        }
    });
}
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: como eu faço para usar a variável `alturaTotal` fora da função `pega_imagens`? Sei que devo usar uma função `callback`, mas não sei como incluí-la no código.

**UPDATE**

Fiz alguns ajustes no código, colocando todas as ações que estavam em `success` na função de callback:

```
function pega_imagens(id_projeto, callback){
    var id_projeto = id_projeto;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({ id_projeto: id_projeto }),
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'php/imagens.php',
        success: function(data){
            foo(data, id_projeto);
        }, 
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('erro' + data);
        }
    });
}

 function foo(data, id_projeto){
    var toAppend = '';
    toAppend += '<div class="gutter-sizer"></div><div class="grid-sizer"></div>';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        toAppend += '<img class="item" src="img/' + data[i].imagem + '" width="' + data[i].largura + '" height="' + data[i].altura + '" />';
    }

    $('#project-expander-images-'+id_projeto).append(toAppend);
    alturaTotal = $('#project-expander-images-'+id_projeto).height();
    console.log(alturaTotal);
 }
```

Mas o valor retornado pela variável `alturaTotal` está incorreto.

Comment: Olá @marcelo2605, onde exatamente você precisa usar este valor? - seria na continuidade do primeiro bloco, após chamar o `pega_imagens(id_projeto);`? se em outro lugar, poderia exemplificar?

Comment: @GêBender É exatamente neste lugar que irei usar o valor.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a altura total deve ser obtida apenas onde necessária ou até mesmo em outra função, pois não parece ser uma das funcionalidades da função `pega_imagens`.

Ao que entendi, o seu problema mesmo está em executar o código que irá utilizar a altura total após executar o ajax. Se for isso, uma função de callback, como você mesmo citou, resolve o problema.

```
pega_imagens(id_projeto, function() {
    var alturaTotal = $('#project-expander-images-'+id_projeto).height();
    console.log(alturaTotal);
});

function pega_imagens(id_projeto, callback){
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function() {
            // ...
            if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: O código está correto? Tentei executá-lo e apareceu Uncaught ReferenceError: id_projeto is not defined

Comment: Também acho que cada coisa é uma coisa. Que tal apenas trocar essa linha `alturaTotal = $('#project-expander-images-'+id_projeto).height();`do segundo para o primeiro bloco, colocando logo abaixo da `pega_imagens(id_projeto);`. Como você já fez o append, deve poder acessar a nova div.

Comment: @GêBender Veja a alteração que fiz no código.

Comment: @marcelo2605 Quanto ao `Uncaught ReferenceError`, você colocou a chamada da função `pega_imagens` no mesmo lugar em que estava antes (no final da função do onclick)? Quanto a sua edição, se o valor da altura não está correto é por algum motivo externo, o código está correto. Talvez as imagens estejam com `float`. Se for este o caso, a div externa (que você está tentando pegar a altura) não irá se ajustar as imagens. Leia [este post](http://edsonjunior.com/entendendo-float-clear-clearfix/) para entender melhor o problema com o float.

Comment: @Oeslei As imagens estão com float. Mas mesmo assim eu não consigo pegar a altura da div que aparece no DOM?

Comment: @marcelo2605 Você consegue ler a altura, mas a mesma estará incorreta devido ao float. Leia o post que lhe passei para entender melhor. Para resolver este problema, utilize uma das soluções apresentadas no post ou troque o estilo `float` para `display: inline-block`.